# Error while creating tablespaces with datafiles of procided size

Tags: database, oracle11g, database-administration

I am using below command to create a tablespae but it is showing below error:

SQL Command: "create tablespace tbs3 datafile '/disk2/prod1/data/data03.dbf' size 10m block size 16k;"

ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02180: invalid option for CREATE TABLESPACE

However I've followed some steps suggested by support.oracle

"SQL> create pfile from spfile;"

but still nothing. Kindly help and also all objects and params are valid also :)

Answer (score 0):

The syntax of this statement is incorrect. Use BLOCKSIZE (one word) not BLOCK SIZE.

Oracle syntax is here https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_7003.htm